# Proving every planar graph have vertex cover of size of at most 3n/4

Tags: graph-theory

Question title says it all: How it can be proved that every planar graph on n vertices have vertex cover of size of at most 3n/4.

I came across this fact when I was reading a textbook. However I am unsure if this is in fact correct. And if it is how it can be proved?

Comment: What is $n$? Number of vertices?  Of edges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a consequence of the four color theorem. Take a planar graph $G$, and color it in 4 colors. All vertices except the ones in the color class of greatest size form a vertex cover consisting of at most $3|V(G)|/4$ vertices.

Comment: Thanks @perry but can I get a bit more elaboration about how 3n/4 number comes? any link?

Comment: @awellwisher The color class of greatest size must have at least $n/4$ vertices (if it had fewer, there would be fewer than $n$ vertices total). So there must be at most $n - n/4 = 3n/4$ other vertices.

Comment: Does that translates to: Independent set in planar graphs have size at least n/4 ?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Yes, there is an independent set in any planar graph of size at least $n/4$.

Comment: I was revising these concept again. Now, it is not making sense to me how minimum independent set size will be $n/4$. It should be always 1, right? Since its "set of vertices in a graph, no two of which are adjacent". Also it is not making me sense that size of vertex cover is at most $3n/4$, as it should be $n$ since its "set of all vertices is a vertex cover".

Comment: There is an independent set of size AT LEAST n/4. Yes, there is also an independent set of size at least 1. These aren't contradictory. For the vertex cover, you're missing the "there exists" part. THERE EXISTS a vertex cover of size at most 3n/4. There is also a vertex cover of size n. These also are not contradictory.